# How can I rotate jpg image and save?

Tags: android, jpeg, image-rotation

I tried to save a jpg with rotation, but the saved image's size was null.

How can I do this? Should I convert the image to a bitmap using `bitmapfactory`, and then convert to jpg and save?

Please tell me the code or link examples.